# Release Azure Domain

Tags: azure, azure-webapps

I'm building a website/web application for this team and first started it on Azure. But now, we have realized that we would rather have it on something like WordPress. How do we transfer the ownership of the domain?

Comment: Did you purchase domain through Azure?

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to map a custom domain to Azure Web, firstly you need to remove the spending limit on your subscription and buy a custom domain name for Azure App. About the detailed action you could follow the [limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-spending-limit#remove) and the [purchase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain) tutorial.

After these, you could map your domain to your App with this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

If you still have other questions, please let me know.